# Scale down whole website [into iFrame]

Tags: php, scaling

I was wondering if there is a (webbased) way to scale down a whole website and put it into an iframe. [including images etc], so that a user would get a fully functional preview of the website (only for websites without frame busting methods of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The Microsoft propriety `zoom` property could probably do it, but not in most browsers, and not in pages you can't edit the CSS for.

If you want to provide a preview, provide a thumbnail graphic (which would probably be a lot faster for the user to download in most cases anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following with css?

```
body {
  zoom: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats up to javascript or css although it really depends about the browser and its behavior to certain commands.

Comment: So there is no way of providing a URL and a script automatically returns a scaled down version of it or fails to because e.g flash or so?

Comment: You could make a thumbnail image but probably not iframe scale

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to specify the iframe src.

`document.getElementById('myiframe').src = 'my url';`

Comment: How would that scale it down?

Comment: Nevermind, I though you just wanted to have an iframe and control it.